How use an npm package in astro component
In my package.json I have the following package:
   "dependencies": {
    "@company/my-package": "0.1.2024.0.1",
   }

I created an astro component MyPackage.astro.
Do i have to define the script like:
---
import '@company/my-package';
---

Or:
<script>
  import '@company/my-package';
</script>


What does the package contain? The first one is a server side import, the second is client side.

In your Astro component file (e.g.,MyPackage.astro).
Import the package using the following syntax:
<script>
 import '@company/my-package';
</script>

